# WCF Webservice - Failed to invoke the service. The service is offline or inaccessible

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

We have developed the wcf service,when we are calling web service from WCF Test Client to fetch the data, In this case we are getting some exception while calling the WCF web service. I want to log error into html file.

My Code:-

```
        try
        {
            int i = 1;
            int j = 0;
            int k = i / j;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ApplicationError.LogErrors(ex);
        }
```

Web Config :-

```
 <appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
 <system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
 <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"     multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<handlers>
  <remove name="ISAPI-dll"/>
  <add name="ISAPI-dll" path="*.dll" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule"   scriptProcessor="C:\WINDOWS\System32\inetsrv\asp.dll" resourceType="File" requireAccess="None" allowPathInfo="true" preCondition="bitness64"/>
</handlers>
<directoryBrowse enabled="false"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Error :-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't log directly from WCF into HTML (or rather, you could but shouldn't).

What you could rather do is throw a `FaultException` with an appropriate message and have your ASP.NET page handle the `Exception` and render an HTML page with the appropriate `Exception.Message` (I prefer `Exception.ToString()` ) in it.

For more information have a look at this link: [Fault Handling in WCF Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942778.aspx)